# Angular Cli 6 Read Environment Name

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli-v6

I have different environments added to my angular.json file, as described here.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-application-environments

When I start my app e.g. via `--configuration=prod` my environment.prod.ts file gets loaded. So far so good.

Now I want to check in one of my components which environment is currently selected. But I do not know where I can get this information. One solution would be to add a new property e.g. `envName : "envNameXYZ"` to each of my environment files, but this is error prone and tedious.

Is there any other solution how to get the environment (name)?

Answer (score 3):

Best solution is to add a new property `envName` in each of your environment files.
No other possibility to know the environment name.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested in how I solved it here is my code:

> envTypeConfig.ts

```
export class EnvTypeConfig {

  readonly type: EnvType.TYPE;

  constructor(type: EnvType.TYPE) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  isStaging() : boolean {
    return this.type == EnvType.TYPE.STAGING;
  }
}


export namespace EnvType {

  export enum TYPE {
    DEV = "dev",
    STAGING = "staging",
    FEATURE = "feature",
    PROD = "prod",
  }


}
```

> environment.staging.ts

```
import {EnvType, EnvTypeConfig} from "./envTypeConfig";

export const environment = {
  envType: new EnvTypeConfig(EnvType.TYPE.STAGING)
};
```

And in my components I can simply execute following snippet to check if staging env is selected:

```
 if(environment.envType.isStaging()){
   console.log("Yippie we are in staging environment!");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

there is experimental isDevMode function available but this wont cover custom ones you made...

https://angular.io/api/core/isDevMode